# Не работает проверка на email

Tags: php, mysql

```
Не работает проверка на второй email!
То-есть на один email можно зарегистрировать хоть сколько пользователей!

$sql_proverka = mysql_query("SELECT `email`, count(*) as `count` FROM `$CONFIG[tbl_uc]` WHERE `email`='".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email'])."'");
$row_proverka = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql_proverka);

    if($row_proverka['count'] > '0') {$error = true; $errormsg .= '<p class="alert">Такая почта уже есть!</p>';}
```

Comment: тогда хз. значит проблема не в этом участке кода

Comment: @Куб, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Comment: @Куб, а точно значение достается из БД? По шагам все разбейте и выводите в лог, а там смотрите, где закралась проблема.

Comment: @Куб, если честно, меня даже Ваши кавычки в запросе чего-то смущают.

Answer (score 1):

```
$sql_proverka = mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $CONFIG[tbl_uc] WHERE email='".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email'])."'"), 0);

if ($sql_proverka == 0) { 
$error = true; 
} else {
$errormsg .= '<p class="alert">Такая почта уже есть!</p>'; 
}
```

Comment: тож не работает! Все равно регистрирует!

Comment: ну то покажите все ваши коды!!!! И базу данных! Хотите получить ответ - предоставьте всевозможные данные!

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql_proverka = mysql_query("SELECT email FROM $CONFIG[tbl_uc] WHERE email='".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email'])."'");

if (mysql_num_rows($sql_proverka)) {
    $error = true; 
    $errormsg .= '<p class="alert">Такая почта уже есть!</p>';
}
```

Расширение mysql уже устарело и скоро будет удалено. Юзайте [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/ru/book.mysqli.php) или [PDO](http://php.net/manual/ru/book.pdo.php)

Comment: не работает

Answer (score 0):

У себя на сервере я реализовываю вот так:

```
$db->sql_query('SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `id` = "'.$id.'"');
$count2 = $db->sql_numrows();
if($count2 == 0){

}
```